# Is it possible to track a user's time frame of the visit on a remote site?

Tags: javascript, tracking

Let's say I have my own website, my own database and I want to give a javascript snippet out to other sites (like google analytics type of deal). How would I be able to track the amount a visitor spends on those websites? How does google analytics do it?

Comment: With javascript. The owners of those sites have to willingly plug your js into their sites. From there they send data bact to your servers.

Comment: yep that's fine. How would I track how long the visitor stays on their site/bounce rate like google analytics? Is there some algorithm for that or some kind of logic?

Comment: It's hard to summarize that in a nutshell. Pretty much anything you can do in javascript is possible. You would log the time on page load, then the time on before unload. post to your server on before unload and choose to evaluate the data however you want from there.

Comment: Could you point me to the right direction? Maybe some guide or tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your javascript you give the client you may provide something like this:

```
    var timeLog = {
        start: null,
        end: null,
        init: function(){
            this.start = new Date().getTime();
        },
        sendResults: function(){
            this.end = new Date().getTime();
            var jData = { "client": "some-access-string", "start": this.start, "end": this.end };

            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client.open("POST", "http://yoursite.com/youre-processing-script.php");
            client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
            client.send(JSON.stringify(jData));
        }
    };

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        timeLog.sendResults();
    };

    timeLog.init();
```

onload you need to call timeLog.init();

onbeforeunload calls timeLog.sendResults();

Your php script needs to evaluate post and log the results based on the client token passed.
So when someone subscribes to your service you provide them with an id. This is the "client" part of the http request above.
From that you should have enough data for basic stats.

Keep in mind this is a rough guide. The intention here is to give you an idea on how to do it, not necessarily write a functioning script. Since you're talking analytics, there are thousands of different things to consider that you may or may not want to include. The math varies depending on your needs.

I don't know what your skill level is per say, so I don't want to make the assumption you need to be guided on the whole process. For that reason I assume you can handle the php part, including database action and general evaluation.

Comment: Yes I am more of a php guy so I can handle the php part. What if I want to track if the person went to a different part of the page because that's still unload but that's still means the user is staying on that domain/page. So that shouldn't count as a user leaving that site.

Comment: You could set a cookie in javascript that is attached to a unique id. Like a randomly generated string based on the date so it doesn't overlap with id's from the past. Then you just include that in your http request post. A basic search on google for javascript cookies will clear that up and js conditionals are not too dissimilar from php, so a conditional in the init that generates the id if there is no cookie should be easy to add to this example.